JavaScript: Can't set value to textarea with custom class on the first load
Question: I am trying to programmatically set a value inside a textarea with the following code:


function setTextareaValue(textareaId, value) {
  // Recursive function to wait until the element is available
  function waitForTextarea() {
    const textareaElement = document.getElementById(textareaId);
    if (textareaElement && textareaElement.querySelector('.hwt-input')) {
      // Once the element is available, set the value
      const textareaInput = textareaElement.querySelector('.hwt-input');
      textareaInput.value = value;
      textareaInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
      textareaInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
    } else {
      // If the element is not available, try again after 100ms
      setTimeout(waitForTextarea, 100);
    }
  }

  // Start the recursive function
  waitForTextarea();
}

// Use the function to set the value to the textarea
setTextareaValue('MarcEditorPresenter.textArea.050.Left.6', 'Value set by code');



However, this doesn’t work the first time I open the form. If I manually click and type in the field, then run the script again, it still doesn’t work. It only works when I open the "Inspect" tool, click on the textarea code in the inspector, and then the value is set correctly.
I've tried debugging, simulating the textarea activation in code, but it still doesn’t work. Any ideas on why this might happen and how to solve it?


If the textarea is a FormControl you can set its initial value when you define the form.
If it is not a FormControl you can use @ViewChild and the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook to access it and set it's value:
// app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <textarea #myTextarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // Get reference to the textarea element
  @ViewChild('myTextarea') textareaRef!: ElementRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>;
  

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Set initial value after view is initialized
    this.textareaRef.nativeElement.value = 'Initial text set after view init';
  }

}


As a side note Angular provides many inbuilt utilities for manipulating the template (ElementRef, TemplateRef, Renderer2) and these should always be preferred over direct DOM access such as getElementById and querySelector

I’m unable to modify the app’s source code to use Angular’s built-in utilities like @ViewChild and AfterViewInit. Instead, I need a solution that allows me to interact with and set the value of the  programmatically from the browser console.
Is there an approach to reliably interact with Angular’s FormControl or similar components via the console without modifying the app’s source code?
